# Because a cookie’s SameSite attribute was not set or is invalid, it defaults to SameSite=Lax

Tags: python, html, css, django

I've been working on a Django project, I'm using Pycharm community edition 2021 and Django version as 4.0.3, the problem is that , whenever I reload my site there are no pictures shown which I want to display from another website. Error is like this "Indicate whether to send a cookie in a cross-site request by specifying its Same Site attribute", I have tried much more method to resolve this by adding removing cookies but unable to solve it, as I dnt know whether these same site cookies bug is in IDE , Django or chrome?

```
 {% extends 'base.html'%}
 {% block body %}
 <div class="container  my-4 mx-4 py-8 px-8" >
 <div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="carousel-item active">
  <img src="https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?&client_id=wIXk0jpTFTYBNuisfNDCRmfWDt- 
  ZDTXZhBtviWWN7U8&query=office" class="d-block  w-100 " alt="...">
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item">
   <img src="https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=wIXk0jpTFTYBNuisfNDCRmfWDt- 
   ZDTXZhBtviWWN7U8&query=office" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
   </div>
   <div class="carousel-item">
   <img src="https://api.unsplash.com/search/photos?client_id=wIXk0jpTFTYBNuisfNDCRmfWDt- 
   ZDTXZhBtviWWN7U8&query=office" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
   </div>
   </div>
   <button class="carousel-control-prev" type="button" data-bs- 
   target="#carouselExampleControls" 
   data-bs-slide="prev">
   <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="visually-hidden">Previous</span>
   </button>
   <button class="carousel-control-next" type="button" data-bs- 
   target="#carouselExampleControls" 
   data-bs-slide="next">
   <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
   <span class="visually-hidden">Next</span>
   </button>
   </div>
   </div>
   {% endblock body %}
```

Comment: is this a question on python or html ?

Comment: Project is in python but this is a design template using html and css I have taken from Bootstrap.